# PHP searchbar not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a searchbar that search for the title .. database is working , content showing under searchbar then i search sth , it show me "connection succesfully and then no results .. what's wrong ?

```
<?php 
include 'header.php';
?>

<h3>Rezultate</h3>
<div class"article-container">
<?php 

  if ($conn->connect_error) 
  {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
   else 
  echo "Connected successfully";

        if(isset($_POST['submit-search']))
        {

            $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE a_title LIKE '%search%'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($queryResult >0)
        {
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                echo"<div>
                        <h3>".$row['a_title']."</h3>
                        <p>".$row['a_text']."</p>
                        <p>".$row['a_author']."</p>
                        <p>".$row['a_dat']."</p>
                     </div>";
        }
            else 
            {
                echo "<br>No result!";
            }
        }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to include the variable `%$search%`

Comment: @Richard where ?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE a_title LIKE '%search%'";`

Comment: The $ in front of search

Comment: Instead of simply fixing this typo, you should _really_ change this to use prepared statements and bound parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL is wrong, when referencing the variable `$search` in the SQL query. Just change the `%search%` to `%$search%`:

```
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE a_title LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Also, I strongly believe you should consider using Prepared Statements for anything which involves user input.

```
$search = "%" . $_POST['search'] . "%";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE a_title LIKE ?";
if($stmt = $mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $search);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $district);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    printf("%s Search Result: %s\n", $search);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

This will protect you a bit more against SQL Injections.

Comment: With the bound approach the `$search` assignment will need to have the `%`s added.

Comment: Hey @chris85; you're right... I hadn't thought of it.

Comment: Don't escape with the binding, you'll end up with a very strange string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE a_title LIKE '%search%'";
```

Your current query is searching for terms like the string "search". Fix it so it's a PHP variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE a_title LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Comment: Thx bro , my mistake

Comment: @user9587848 Literally said that as the first comment

Comment: @Richard didn't see it. Why did you put it as a comment if it is the answer?

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include a solution that would not open the door to SQL Injections. :: Certainly this will fix the immediate issue, but it propagates poor programing technique and therefore should not be offered as a solution. SQL Injections techniques are still successful only because beginners and intermediate programmers still implement this type of weak coding suggestions.